# Flask - Test Case Failure on Hackerank Env- saved session variable username while rendering template via jinja

Tags: python, flask

Login html page accepts - user name and Password. The test script is fixed in the test environment

login.html:

```
   <!-- write a form get the input from the user -->
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/login/" method="POST">
            <p>Enter Username:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="username" /></p>
            <p>Enter Password:</p>
            <p><input type="password" name="password" /></p>
    
            <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Route /login/ endpoint is used for logging in user. The user can log in by giving their username and password. Once logged in, store the session ##variable username to value obtained from a submitted form. Respose:  on sucessful login, return /user/ route

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
  # if form is submited
    if request.method == "POST":
        # record the user name
        session['username'] = request.form.get("username")
        # redirect to the main page
        return redirect("/user/")
    return render_template("login.html")
```

route /user/ endpoint is used to get the username in the session.
Response:
If user in the session, return a response "Logged in as {{username}}" or
return a response "You are not logged in"

```
@app.route("/user/")
def user():
    loggeduser = session.get('username')
    if not loggeduser:
      #return "You are not logged in"
      print("Do Nothing")
    return render_template('user.html' , logged = loggeduser)
```

*user.html*

```
<!-- write a condition to check if the user in session or not with appropriate response and redirect routes-->
<html lang="en">
<body>
{% block content %}
<!-- write a condition to check if the user in session or not with appropriate response and redirect routes-->
    {% if logged %}
       <p id="a">Logged in as {{ session['username'] }} </p>
       <a href="/logout">logout</a>
    {%else%}
       <p id="b">You are not logged in</p>
       <a href="/login">login</a>.
    {%endif %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

*Test Script:(This is fixed and can't be altered in the test environment*

```
import os
import pytest
import requests
from app import app
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Test_API:
    client = app.test_client()

    def test_login(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:5000/login'
        payload = "{'username': 'admin', 'password': 'test'}"
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
        response = self.client.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        assert response.status_code == 308

    def test_user(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:5000/user/'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
        response = self.client.get(url, headers=headers)
        assert response.status_code == 200

    def test_logout(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:5000/logout/'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
        response = self.client.get(url, headers=headers)
        assert response.status_code == 200


class Test_Webpage:
    def get_soup1(self):
        post_params = {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'test'}
        source = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/login/", data=post_params)
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
        return soup1

    def get_soup2(self):
        source = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/user/")
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
        return soup2

    def get_soup3(self):
        source = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/logout/")
        soup3 = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
        return soup3

    def get_soup4(self):
        post_params = {'username': 'user', 'password': 'demo'}
        source = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/login/", data=post_params)
        soup4 = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
        return soup4

    def test_login_and_user_page(self):
        soup1 = self.get_soup1()
        msg = soup1.find('p', {'id': 'a'})
        link = soup1.find('a')
        assert msg.text == 'Logged in as admin'
        assert link['href'] == '/logout'

        soup3 = self.get_soup3()
        assert soup3.text == "You've been logged out successfully!"

        soup4 = self.get_soup4()
        msg = soup4.find('p', {'id': 'a'})
        assert msg.text == 'Logged in as user'

    def test_user_page(self):
        soup2 = self.get_soup2()
        msg = soup2.find('p', {'id': 'b'})
        link = soup2.find('a')
        assert msg.text == 'You are not logged in'
        assert link['href'] == '/login'
```

*Test Case Failure:*

```
=========== FAILURES =======================
______________ Test_Webpage.test_login_and_user_page ___________

self = <tests.Test_Webpage object at 0x7f8b4cad2be0>

    def test_login_and_user_page(self):
        soup1 = self.get_soup1()
        msg = soup1.find('p', {'id': 'a'})
        link = soup1.find('a')
>       assert msg.text == 'Logged in as admin'
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

tests.py:58: AttributeError
=========== short test summary info ===========
FAILED tests.py::Test_Webpage::test_login_and_user_page - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my code**

app.py

```
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request,session
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = 'asdfhj828r0ha;hfu'

    # use the route '/login/' to login user

    @app.route('/login/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
    def login():
      if request.method == 'POST':
         session['username'] = request.form['username']
         return redirect(url_for('user'))
      return render_template('login.html')

    # use the route '/user/' to get the username in the session


    @app.route('/user/')
    def user():
      return render_template('user.html')

    # use the route '/logout/' to logout user
    @app.route('/logout/')
    def logout():
      session.pop('username',None)
      return "You've been logged out successfully!"
```

login.html

```
    <form action="" method="post">
          <p>User Name : <input type='text' name='username'/></p>
          <p>Password : <input type='text' name='password'/></p>
          <p><input type='submit' value='Login'/></p>
    </form>
```

user.html

```
    {% if session['username'] %}
        <p id="a">Logged in as {{ session['username'] }}</p>
        <a href="/logout">logout</a>
        {%else%}
        <p id="b">You are not logged in</p>
        <a href="/login">login</a>
        {%endif %}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?